# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL Can someone see where I went wrong?

Tags: javascript

```
function newReply(username, userImage, text)
{
return "<div class='reply'>
            <div class='user-picture-reply'><img class='img-circle' height='30' src='" + userImage +  "'></div> \
            <div class='reply-arrow-left'></div> \
            <div class='reply-content'>"+ text + "</div> \
            <div class='reply-username'>Posted by " + username + " just now</div> \
        </div>";
}
```

It's been a long day of coding can anyone see whats causing this error? Says its at line `74` which is the line with the `return`

Comment: Please post the rest of your code.  CSS, HTML, any more JS?

Comment: Your string is missing a ``\`` on the first line.

Comment: whoops, my bad. Deleting my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line needs a `\` following the first div.

Let me know if that works, if not is it same error?

That is the only syntax error I see, other than that the code looks fine.

If this is still throwing an error perhaps provide context?

EDIT: looks like someone already answered in comments, good luck!